# Laravel5 installation

Tags: laravel-5

I am new in laravel5.

i'm successfully installed laravel in xampp server.

I am try to run "**php artisan serve**" but not working properly

This command did not launch system’s PHP server on port 8000

Please find the attached screen shot below,

[image]

i am try to run "**php artisan serve**"  in my **first laravel project** in working fine

But show some Error msg displayed in command prompt.

Please find screen shot below

[image]

Comment: Do you made any changes in `public` or any other folder directly ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : No I didn’t make any changes to folder directly.

Comment: You're running withing single system or using within networks ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : i'm using within networks

Comment: Can you try `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` replace the 0.0.0.0 with you ip ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : this tricks for first screen or second screen ?

Comment: Just try it in the composer i.e., first screen itself :)

Comment: not working same msg displayed in command prompt

Comment: What ip do you given for your local machine ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : 103.27.171.51

Comment: are you having trouble with the error Invlid request @GobinathMahalingam

Comment: if so I think its problem with your code @GobinathMahalingam

Comment: in your project directory , run `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gobinath Mahalingam,

If all the required packages are installed then this should work:

```
php artisan serve
```

If not, try:

```
composer install
```

If you don't have composer installed, head towards: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Obviously, this is the last option:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHP built-in server command directly which exactly what `php artisan serve` command does in the background.

Firstly cd into your project directory:

`cd /xampp/htdocs/laravel/first-project`

The run this command:

`php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Answer (score 1):

I try

c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel> **php -S localhost:8000 -t public**

Now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

laravel5 doesn't support the serve function anymore. It is no more included in the basic package (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/80fb944e45801cec81b459f73892dbfc80c39de6). You can add it by hand if you seriously need it. But you can also use:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```